# Как поменять спрайт кнопки в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создаю простой кликер в 2д юнити на андроид и столкнулся с такой проблемой,что хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку менялся спрайт(кнопки), а при отжатии
Менялся на прежний спрайт(кнопки).Нигде не нашел ответ на данный вопрос,а так как являюсь новичком опыта как и ума у меня не хватает

Comment: *"так как являюсь новичком опыта как и ума у меня не хватает"* --- а книги какие-нибудь читали по юнити? А то базовые вещи там рассказаны

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению в Unity нет события на отжатие кнопки у самой кнопки. Поэтому добавим компонент `Event Trigger` и добавим 2 типа событий: `Pointer up` и `Pointer down`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь создаём по одному ивенту для каждого события (кнопка `+`). После переносим объект нашей кнопки в поля для объектов и выбираем событие `Image` -> `overrideSprite`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вызов данного метода заменяет спрайт объекта на тот, который мы передали в параметры. Таким образом для события `Pointer Down` можно назначить спрайт, который будет включаться при зажатии кнопки, а для события `Pointer Up` можно назначить изначальный спрайт, что бы при отжатии спрайт кнопки менялся на исходный

Comment: *"в Unity нет события на отжатие кнопки у самой кнопки"*  --- вроде бы есть  https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html   ... если мы об ондой и той же кнопке думаем, конечно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ну как бы да, но не через инспектор, а писать скрипт для этого такое себе... Если он не планирует это делать для множества кнопок

Comment: *"как бы да, но не через инспектор"* --- А разве в вопросе написано, что "нужно исключительно через инспектор"?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, никакого `UnityEvent` для `Pointer Up` в инспекторе `Button` нет и быть не должно. Что касается события, оно обрабатывается любым `Selectable`, в методе `OnPointerUp()`, реализацию которого можно переопределить.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `А разве в вопросе написано` но почему-то ты комментируешь не вопрос, а ответ.

Comment: @Yaroslav и что? К чему предъява?

Comment: Спасибо огромное мой проект будет жить